# How to add a standalone app to Zend

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a site I've made with Zend and I want to add a forum that is a standalone app and it works on its own, but since it's not a zend app and it doesn't have modules I can't implement it as such. I know I can route it using htaccess, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. The forum directory is in the root folder of the zend app and the URL has to be site/forum. My htaccess is the default one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your `htaccess`

Remove/change Directory rules

```
<Directory "Path_Of_Zend_Root_Folder">
 RewriteEngine Off
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Add Alias too

```
<IfModule alias_module>
 Alias /forum "Path_Of_Zend_Root_Folder/Forum_Directory"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I put this at the bottom of the .htaccess and I changed the direcory to "/", but the site gave me error 500